# HTTP file download directly to media server

Tags: http, url, ftp, router

I have usb drive connected to router. Is it possible to dowload file from internet directly to this drive. On computer i'm connected over wifi and i'm losing download speed because of wifi. Any suggestions?

Comment: This is possible if you have a way to start a http request _on that router_, so if you can execute code on it (which I doubt). You can _not_ somehow "redirect" a request response to some other system or file hierarchy or something like that.